# JQuery on click animation not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

**Problem**

So, I have a `h2` and inside the `h2` there is a `i` and when you click on the `h2`, the `.inputs` underneath the `h2` `slideToggle()`'s. My problem is that when the `h2` is clicked on, I want the `i` to rotate `90deg`.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="toggle-inputs">Add Student <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

                <form class="inputs" action="server/add/add-student.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="student-id" placeholder="* Student ID...">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="* Firstname...">
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="* Lastname...">
                    <input type="text" name="teacher-firstname" placeholder="* Teacher's Firstname...">
                    <input type="text" name="teacher-lastname" placeholder="* Teacher's Lastname...">
                    <span class="spare">Spare Block<input type="checkbox" name="spare"></span>

                    <button type="submit" name="add-student"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Student</button>
                </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// MAIN
function main() {
    $(".toggle-inputs").on("click", toggleInputs);
}

// TOGGLE INPUTS
function toggleInputs() {
    $(this).parent().find('.inputs').slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(this).children('i').animate({
            "transform": "rotate(90deg)",
        });
    });
}

// LOAD
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: You end by saying that your problem is ... only to then say what you want to happen. What problem are you having? Are you getting an error? What does happen? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just not animating

Answer (score 0):

You are using Font Awesome. Wouldn't it be easier to simply change the class from fa-caret-down to fa-caret-left/fa-caret-right as required

Comment: but I want the icon  to have a rotation animation when it's clicked on